# Access IndexedDB as a file from javascript to encrypt it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encryption, sjcl

I have created an indexedDB with pouchDB in my angular webapp. Each time I close my app, I would like to be able to encrypt this database file. So I had the idea of encrypting the database file with [SJCL](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/). My web app will be accessible only when the user can insert his password that will correctly decrypt.

So my first question is how can I access the indexedDB file within javascript so I can encrypt/decrypt the whole file? Secondly, what do you think of this idea of encrypting/decrypting the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the IndexedDB file directly.  Your best bet would be to use the crypto library to encrypt the documents that you're passing into PouchDB.  E.g.:

```
pouch.put({
  _id: 'myid', 
  sensitiveData: whateverLibrary.encryptString('secret')
});
```

If you wanted, you could even implement this as [a PouchDB plugin](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#plugins)!  Basically you would just need to override the get/put/post/allDocs/bulkDocs methods to encrypt the documents before they're passed to PouchDB itself.

Comment: Thanks...it doesn't seem to be a good solution as I'll have to encrypt/decrypt each of my request (which might take a lot of resources). Encrypting/Decrypting the database would be much more efficient. I'm still wondering how I can create a secure app with offline abilities...

Comment: [WebCrypto](http://html5.creation.net/webcrypto-api/) should alleviate most of your performance concerns, but it's not implemented in every browser yet.  You could use a polyfill for browsers that don't support it.